# How do you create a folder containing all the files in a project?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, project, documents

I'm creating an application In `C#` that shows a dialog on startup and will ask for the project name. Meanwhile, there are 2 buttons I added: `Create` and `Exit`.

If you'd press create, the name of the project you'd type in the `TextBox` will be saved with that name in the Documents folder. Inside the project folder will be containing 2 separate folders called `img` and `js`. And if you tried the next time to create a project with a name that the folder exists, It will not overwrite the folder (let's just say i showed up a `MsgBox`). Here's the code:

```
//Unable to create project
        string mydir = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments + "\\" + textBox1.Text;
        if (Directory.Exists(mydir) == true)
        {
                MessageBox.Show("The project name: " + textBox1.Text + " has already been created. Please consider renaming a different project name.", "Netplait", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                textBox1.Focus();
                return;
        }

        if (Directory.Exists(mydir) == false)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), textBox1.Text));
        }
```

Comment: So you are asking about how to delete folder and create a new one or how to detect that folder already exists?

Comment: Create a folder directory with the Textbox input name, then if we typed the same project name like we did before, it will detect and disable request

Comment: You need to call [Directory.Exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists(v=vs.110).aspx) method

Comment: I tried doing that it did not work. Ill edit my post and add the code real quick

Comment: Why don't you already use `Path.Combine` when initializing `mydir`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx)* is an enum, not a path to an existing directory. Your code fails because concatenating this enum value to the string in the textbox makes no sense.

Instead you get the actual MyDocument folder with

```
string mydir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environement.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
mydir = Path.Combine(myDir, textBox1.Text);
if(DirectoryExists(myDir))
{
    MessageBox.Show(.....);
    textBox1.Focus();
    return;
}
else
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(myDir);
}
```

Notice also that to combine string and make valid paths it is better to leave this task to the specialized method [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx).
By the way, you have it right in the Directory.CreateDirectory part of your code.